# How to split date last 7 day from now

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to split date last 7 day from now.

This is my code.

```
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo('ibm',
                          start=datetime.datetime(y-5, m, d),
                          end=pd.datetime.now().date())

split_date = datetime.datetime(y, m, d-7)
train = df.loc[:split_date, ['Close']]
test = df.loc[split_date:, ['Close']]

print(train)
print("################################")
print(test)
```

It show result like this.

```
............
2019-01-25  133.970001
2019-01-28  134.270004
2019-01-29  134.330002
2019-01-30  134.380005
2019-01-31  134.419998
2019-02-01  134.100006
##################################################################
                 Close
Date                  
2019-02-01  134.100006
2019-02-04  135.190002
2019-02-05  135.550003
2019-02-06  136.320007
2019-02-07  133.000000
```

`print(test)` should show data last 7 day but why it show 5 day only, and why `2019-02-01  134.100006` show in train and test the data split should not same.

Comment: The days are *weekdays*.  Assuming `d` is today's day, `d-7` only give you one week's slice.  One week only have 5 weekdays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It seems that there were only 5 rows (weekdays) in your dataset from the last 7 days, which is why your test set only shows 5 rows.
- The reason why '2019-02-01' is included in both your train and test sets is because `df.iloc[start_ind:end_ind]` retrieves rows from `start_ind` to `end_ind` **both inclusive**. (This is mentioned as a warning in the docs. You can check [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).) To split correctly, you can include all dates till 8 days ago in your train test and include last 7 days in your test set.